# Failed attempts at fitting nonlinear Hill function (biochemistry) to data

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to fit some data in Matlab to a Hill function of the form $y = \dfrac{1}{1+(K/r)^n}.$ I have data for $r,y$ and I need to find $K,n$.

I have tried following the approach shown here in Demo $3$ at this link:
http://www.math.ubc.ca/~keshet/MCB2012/SlidesDodo/DataFitLect3.pdf

but I'm getting wrong results. Please help!

Here is my code:

**Function file:**

```
function response = func(x,dose)
EC50 = x(1);
n = x(2);
response = 1./(1+(EC50./dose).^n);
end
```

**Script file:**

```
xdata = (logspace(-2,2,101))';
ydata = [0.0981 0.1074 0.1177 0.1289 0.1411 0.1545 0.1692 0.1852 0.2027 ...
          0.2219 0.2428 0.2656 0.2905 0.3176 0.3472 0.3795 0.4146 0.4528 ...
          0.4944 0.5395 0.5886 0.6418 0.6994 0.7618 0.8293 0.9022 0.9808 ...
          1.0655 1.1566 1.2544 1.3592 1.4713 1.5909 1.7183 1.8537 1.9972 ...
          2.1490 2.3089 2.4770 2.6532 2.8371 3.0286 3.2272 3.4324 3.6437 ...
          3.8603 4.0815 4.3065 4.5344 4.7642 4.9950 5.2258 5.4556 5.6833 ...
          5.9082 6.1292 6.3457 6.5567 6.7616 6.9599 7.1511 7.3347 7.5105 ...
          7.6783 7.8379 7.9893 8.1324 8.2675 8.3946 8.5139 8.6257 8.7301 ...
          8.8276 8.9184 9.0029 9.0812 9.1539 9.2212 9.2834 9.3408 9.3939 ...
          9.4427 9.4877 9.5291 9.5672 9.6022 9.6343 9.6638 9.6909 9.7157 ...
          9.7384 9.7592 9.7783 9.7957 9.8117 9.8263 9.8397 9.8519 9.8630 ...
          9.8732 9.8826]';
guess = [1 1];
betaHat = nlinfit(xdata,ydata,@func,guess);
semilogx(xdata,ydata,'ro','MarkerSize',8)
hold on
plot(xdata,func(betaHat,xdata));
```

I am getting the `Warning: Imaginary parts of complex X and/or Y arguments ignored`

and here is my abysmal graph:
[Red = data, blue = bad fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTqPf.jpg)

**I have used `nlinfit` from the Statistics toolbox.**

Comment: Can you figure out which line of your program triggers the warning (by just running each line one after the other interactively)? You are probably doing something simple wrong.

Comment: Ok, I will try running it in debug mode.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem now: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101851-why-does-nlinfit-result-in-complex-beta-parameters-in-statistics-toolbox-7-3-r2010a So instead of using the function $f(r;K,n)=\frac{1}{1+(K/r)^n}$, try the function $g(r;a,n)=\frac{1}{1+a/r^n}$. Then at the end you can recompute $K$ from $a$ and $n$.

Comment: That looks slick! Thank you. Would have never guessed that the math was the issue; thought I was coding something wrong. I will give it a try.

Comment: It's not exactly that your math was wrong, it's that you needed the assumption that $K$ remains nonnegative throughout the computation. But nlinfit does not guarantee this, which created the problems that you saw here. You can bypass this by switching to a parametrization of the problem in which no constraints are necessary, like the one I suggested.

Comment: Actually, I think you have a problem in your setup: in the Hill equation, the $y$ values are between $0$ and $1$, but your $y$ data is not between $0$ and $1$. The only way for the $y$ data to *not* be between $0$ and $1$ is to have $K<0$. nlinfit figured that out, but also was trying to use floating point values of $n$, which is where the complex numbers came from. Is it possible you need another parameter, such as a factor in the numerator? Or is it possible that your data is wrong?

Comment: I think I have been using wrong, non-normalized data this whole time. I will fix that by using the right data set. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: All working now!

Answer (score 0):

Try transforming your equation to a different form? Often fitting can go wrong because of errors piling up in working with very small/large numbers. Sometimes, it can be fixed by transforming the equation to a different form.

I would suggest going in for fitting the logarithmic form of this equation, i.e. getting rid of the exponent. This is a pretty common practice in biochem.

the new form would be -

$log(y/1-y)=nlog(r)-nlog(k)$